# How to prevent "Too many dynamic script compilations within" error with search templates?

Tags: elasticsearch, mustache, elasticsearch-painless

I use a search template with "mustache" language to build dynamic queries according to different parameters.
When I often modify the values ​​of the parameters of this request, I get this error message :
`[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [150/5m];`

I think that each time the values ​​of the parameters change, the script is recompiled but if the values ​​are identical then elasticsearch uses a cache so as not to recompile the script.

In our case, the cache cannot be used because at each request the values ​​are always different (local timestamp, variable distance, random seed generated by a client...)

To prevent this error, I change the cluster settings to increase the `max_compilations_rate` value at the cost of higher server load.

Is there a way to limit recompilation ?

My "big" script computes score according to many parameters and uses Elasticsearch 8.2.

The structure of the script is as follows :

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": "...",
    "params": { ... }
  }
}
```

The source code looks like this :

```
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "is_opened": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": " ... "
        }
     }
    {{#user_location}}
    ,"distance": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": " ... "
        }
    }
    {{/user_location}}     
  },

  "query": {
    "script_score": {
        "query": { ... }
        },
        "script": {
            "source": " ... "
        }
    }
  },

  "fields": [
    "is_opened"
    {{#user_location}},"distance"{{/user_location}}
  ],
  ...
}
```

I use mustache variables (with double brackets) everywhere in the script :

- in the computed fields ("is_opened", "distance")
- in query and filters
- in script score

Is there a way to "optimize" internal scripts (computed fields and score script) so as not to restart compilation each time the values for the parameters change ?

Comment: What value did you set for `max_compilations_rate`?

Comment: I set `3000/5m` to `max_compilations_rate`.

Comment: Try `100000/1m`

Comment: With a big value the error disappeared but I think it's a transitional solution because it increases the load on the server and this value may change as I have more and more calls to this query. I have not yet found a solution to minimize the number of compilations.

Comment: The whole purpose of using parameters in the first place is to minimize the number of compilations, so it's weird that you're getting so many compilations for a small query. Do you mind sharing your query ?

Comment: My request is really huge. I think that using parameters with the `painless` script language does indeed reduce the number of compilations but I'm afraid that this does not apply if I use `mustache` as the script language. I think that elastic needs to merge the parameter values into the `mustache` model and then compile the generated code into Java. In the end, a compilation in Java could be done each time the values of the parameters are merged into the `mustache` model.

Comment: Are you also using params inside the embedded runtime fields scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid compilations, I need to use "params" inside the embedded runtime fields scripts and inside the query score script.

I had indeed used the parameters for the main script written in "mustache" but I had not done so for the embedded scripts written in "painless".

Thanks @Val for giving me a hint.